# Second Site in a week on our Server hacked. How?

Tags: wordpress, hacking

We are a hosting Company for customers and never had problems. Now, the second customer site was "hacked" in one week. Our passwords should be safe and we change them often, instead I think there were backdoors used. One site was an old Joomla! Version. (from 2010). We've shut that down, but now we've got an abuse mail from our provider, because another site was "hacked". This is a wordpress installation (pretty new version, maybe 2-3 months old. As far as I see there has a zipfile `nca.zip` been injected to the root folder, and that has been extracted somehow. All Wordpress files are still there.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: How to prevent it? Get out of the hosting business.

Comment: @EEAA What a qualitative answer from a moderator, beautiful. We're not really hosting, just providing webspaces for small local customers. So instead of being a d*ck, you could maybe give me a more helpul answer, thanks.

Comment: It wasn't an answer. It was a comment. And it was honest. Hosting companies (which you are, even if small) have entire teams of people to deal with this sort of thing, and they shut down customers with reckless abandon when they're discovered to be compromised. Whenever you let customers run their own applications on your infrastructure, you will have to deal with this.

Comment: Maybe it was a bit unclear. We're not letting them run their own applications, we are setting everything up by ourselves and provide them tools with restricted permissions. Maybe you got me wrong, it's not like we ignored every basic security rules but instead I was just wondering what one could use in order to check for joomla/wordpress backdoors etcetera.

Comment: `We're not letting them run their own applications, we are setting everything up by ourselves and provide them tools with restricted permissions.` and `One site was an old Joomla! Version. (from 2010). ` Then you f*ed up yourself...

Comment: Yea, sure I know. That's why we deactivated the site. Tell me something I don't know.

Comment: You cannot wait a month or three to install updates to web applications, like some enterprises try to do (and sometimes get away with). These must be installed _immediately_, as they're exposed to the Internet and malicious parties create exploits as soon as the updates come out, and sometimes even before. 24 hours is too long to wait. Update everything and keep it up to date. That includes on weekends and possibly overnight.

Answer (score 7):

1. Keep your applications updated. This doesn't include just the core application itself, but every third-party plugin you use as well. Vulnerabilities are very frequently found and exploited in these third-party modules. You should quite literally be checking for updates and applying them every day.
2. Join security-related mailing lists for the applications you're using.
3. Put each customer in their own VM to minimize collateral damage in case one gets compromised.
4. Install a IDS/IPS system on your network and/or web hosts. This can help detect and block odd or unexpected traffic on your hosts.

Answer (score 6):

Do what the attackers are doing and scan you customers for common popular and often exploited packages that are out of date/unmaintained by the site owners. Take those off-line before they cause problems.

A better strategy might be to offer a hosted version of such products that your engineering team keeps up to date and current. That shifts the burden from your often not as tech-savvy customers to your staff, who, in theory should be better equipped to respond quickly to security alerts and upstream updates.